# Using where clause to filter an apoc call

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is standard call to filter based on a given label:

```
CALL apoc.meta.nodeTypeProperties({labels: ["Person"]});
```

Can this be re-written with a where clause, e.g. return only rows where nodeLabels contains "Person"?

If so, how? If not, why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done. Please see my example below:

```
CALL apoc.meta.nodeTypeProperties({labels: ["Person"]}) YIELD nodeLabels
MATCH (n) where labels(n) =  nodeLabels 
RETURN n.name  LIMIT 2
```

Call the apoc function and returning the node labels.  Then do a match on node n where the label name is the same with the result of the apoc function. Then return these node n.

```
Sample result:
╒════════╕
│"n.name"│
╞════════╡
│"mary's"│
├────────┤
│"Mary's"│
└────────┘
```